# Running Flask with pycharm

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

[image]

I'm trying to follow https://developers.openshift.com/en/python-flask.html, to set up a flask app on openshift.

I've followed the directions and have got it working at the command line using git-bash on win7.

```
/myflaskapp (master)
$ python wsgi.py
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2015 13:46:10] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2015 13:46:10] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 233
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2015 13:46:10] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 233
```

However as you can see the 'Run' and 'debug' buttons are greyed out, in Pycharm Pro 4.5. How can I get them working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a configuration.  For the simple app you show, all you need to do is execute `flaskapp.py`.  Right click on `flaskapp.py` and chose "Create 'flaskapp'".  You can chose "Edit Configurations..." from the dropdown to the left of the run button to edit the configuration that's created.

Answer (score 4):

**With PyCharm Community Edition 2019 on Windows :**

- Edit your configuration or Create a new configuration
- In "Script path" set the path to flask.exe **(1)**
- Set "Parameters" to run
- Add to "Environment variables"

  - FLASK_APP=yourserverfile.py
  - FLASK_ENV=development

Now you can run your app with Shift+F10 (Release) or Shift+F9 (Debug)

Open a web broswer and go to *http:127.0.0.1:5000*
(if your port is 5000, default port is 5000)

**Below Screenshot of configuration**

[image: pycharm flask configuration]

Notes :

**(1)** Flask.exe should be in the Scripts directory of the Python path, something like "C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\flask.exe"

Comment: Because this gives me an error ('invalid or missing encoding declaration for flask.exe') I had to modify my configuration to use a 'Module name' instead of 'Script path'. The value 'flask' is correct value for me, it is known in my environment.

Comment: I was looking for something similar for uvicorn, and indeed: simply switching to module name allows this. You can't select .exe's in the Script path.

Comment: @MathieuDhondt Just for add info, you can just select Script folder and add flask.exe manually.

Answer (score 1):

1. In `PyCharm Community Edition`, click on the `Terminal` at the bottom. Let it load, and once the command line opens, type in `'flask'`. If the command works, great! If you get an error, try installing Flask again.
2. Type in `set FLASK_APP=example.py` to the terminal, obviously changing 'example' to the name of your Flask file, and click Enter.
3. Type in `flask run`, and let it load.
4. Once you see `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`, click on the PyCharm link, and it should take you to your `localhost`. There you have it! You can now see your webpage.